# Trouble installing PETSc on Mac OS X

Tags: gcc, fortran, scientific-computing, gfortran

I'm trying to install the **PETSc** scientific computation library on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

When configuring the project, I am running into the following error message:

```
cls ~/Downloads/petsc-3.2-p6 $ ./configure
===============================================================================
             Configuring PETSc to compile on your system                       
===============================================================================
TESTING: checkFortranNameMangling from config.compilers(config/BuildSystem/config/compilers.py:589)                              *******************************************************************************
         UNABLE to CONFIGURE with GIVEN OPTIONS    (see configure.log for details):
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Unknown Fortran name mangling: Are you sure the C and Fortran compilers are compatible?
  Perhaps one is 64 bit and one is 32 bit?
  See http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-as/documentation/faq.html#gfortran
*******************************************************************************
```

I have the following versions gcc

```
cls ~/Downloads/petsc-3.2-p6 $ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin10-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

and gfortran

```
cls ~/Downloads/petsc-3.2-p6 $ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (GCC) 4.2.3
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Why are those not compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the two compilers come from two different packages. Maybe you should show us where do their binary reside, for example by using `which gcc` and `which gfortran`. Try to find accompanying build of gfortran to your build of gcc, which comes from `LLVM`. Your gfortran is probably not provided by LLVM, but it is normal gcc build. The installer suggests that they may even be 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: As requested, here is where the binaries reside: 

/usr/local/bin/gfortran

/usr/bin/gcc

"Try to find accompanying build of gfortran to your build of gcc"

I do not understand what "the accompanying build" means in this context.

Comment: From the different path one can guess, that your gfortran is from a diferent source, than gcc. Try to find a LLVM gfortran from the same source you have your gcc from.

Comment: If you run `file /usr/local/bin/gfortran /usr/bin/gcc` it will tell you the architectures that those binaries are built for (i.e. 32-bit and/or 64-bit).

Comment: I googled for "LLVM Gfortran", found [this](http://www.macresearch.org/new-builds-gfortran-and-llvm-gfortran-available) and used it to replace my gfortran binary. Now the PETSc ./configure script runs without problems. Thanks.